# Compactness in $C^\infty(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open, bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$, and let $C^\infty(\Omega)$ denote the space of smooth functions from $\Omega$, into $\mathbb R$, topologized by the seminorms
$$\rho_{K,\alpha}(f)=\sup_{x\in K}|\partial^\alpha f(x)|$$
for $K$ a compact subset of $\Omega$ and $\alpha$ a multi-index.

I'm curious if there is a theorem akin to Ascoli's theorem dealing with compactness in $C^\infty(\Omega)$. Perhaps some condition involving equicontinuity of the derivatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$C^\infty(\Omega)$ is what is called a [Montel space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel_space), that is, a subset $X\subset C^\infty(\Omega)$ is compact if and only if it's closed and bounded. Since it is locally convex, bounded is the same as bounded in every semi-norm.

More explicitly, $X\subset C^\infty(\Omega)$ is precompact if, and only if, for every sequence $(f_n)$ in $X$, the family $X_{K,\alpha} = \left\{\left(\partial^\alpha f_n\right)|_{K};\,n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ is uniformly bounded for every $K\subset \Omega$ compact and $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$ multi-index.

This result is proved, for example, in Tréves' book "Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels", in chapter 14, along with many other results.

Comment: Instead of equicontinuity it is enough that $\sup \{|\partial^\alpha f(x)|: f\in X, x\in K\}<\infty$ for all compact $K$ and all $\alpha$.